# Remove index that isn't followed by an index in other pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Series, I want to filter out data which has an index that is not followed by an index in the other Series. So when joining these Series, based on index, only *every other* datapoint should be from `data1` and vice versa.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1={1:20, 3:30, 5:40, 6:50}
data2={2:10, 4:20, 7:30, 9:40}
data1=pd.Series(data1)
data2=pd.Series(data2)
print(data1)
print(data2)

ax=plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data1,marker='o')
ax.plot(data2,marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Output:
(Arrows show data points which I want filtered out)

```
1    20
3    30
5    40
6    50
dtype: int64
2    10
4    20
7    30
9    40
dtype: int64
```

[image]

Expected pandas function for solving my problem:

```
expectedData1=data1[data1.index.isNotFollowedBy(data2.index)]
expectedData2=data2[data2.index.isNotFollowedBy(data1.index)]
```

Expected output from that function:

```
1    20
3    30

6    50
dtype: int64
2    10
4    20

9    40
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What do you mean by followed by? Why is the fourth point included if the index is 6 in one series and 9 in the other?

Comment: Lets say the indexes are days of the month when something happened. When going through the days you should always have to go to the other series to find the next closest day, if not then remove day.

Comment: @normal_human Are the indices in the two given series always disjoint?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma No just sometimes, so it would have to be some sort of if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two series together in a dataframe and compare them according to your comment using `shift()` and filter out those rows.

```
df = data1.reset_index().join(data2.reset_index(), rsuffix='_y')
df = df[(df['index'].shift(-1) > df['index_y']) | (df['index'] == df['index'].iloc[-1])]
data1 = df.iloc[:,0:2].set_index('index').iloc[:,0]
data2 = df.iloc[:,2:].set_index('index_y').iloc[:,0]
```

Then, you can plot:

```
ax=plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data1,marker='o')
ax.plot(data2,marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks promising! Can you explain in more depth how this function is choosing which values stay and which are removed?

Comment: @normal_human With `shift(-1)`. I am comparing the next row in one of the series to the value in the other series with `(df['index'].shift(-1) > df['index_y'])`. That is the first part of the logic. The second part of the logic is to simply keep the last row `(df['index'] == df['index'].iloc[-1])`. The steps after that are simply there to return the dataframe back to their original series but this time filtering out values that you want to filter out.

Comment: A
lright! However the df['index'] is giving me KeyError 'index'

Comment: Just change `index` and `index_y` to the name of the column that came into your dataframe after using `reset_index()` From my answer, see the output of the columns after running my first line of code by commeting out the other lines of code or moving to a new section of your jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one idea with `Dataframe.align`:

```
m = lambda s: s[s.notna() & s.shift(-1).isna()]
s1, s2 = map(m, data1.align(data2))
```

Result:

```
print(s1)

1    20.0
3    30.0
6    50.0
dtype: float64

print(s2)

2    10.0
4    20.0
9    40.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In what way does this decide which datapoints stay and which are removed?